# Convert shapefile into DXF file including Hebrew labels in QGIS 2.18

Tags: convert, export, qgis-2.18, dxf, encoding

I try to convert this polygon shapefile into DXF including Hebrew labels (this is the QGIS screenshot):

[image]

The data source encoding is UTF8

I opened the dxf file in AutoCad - but there no features in the CAD file.

When export the shapefile in this way:

[image]

I don't understand what is my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finely, i found the solution: i changed the encoding into CP 1255.